# Returning a promised wrapped express route to app.use()

Tags: javascript, express, promise, bluebird

I'm looking to make an express route more modular. I was interested in using a promise to read a file then return the route.

Here's the code:

```
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()
var app = express()

var Promise = require("bluebird")
var fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require("fs"))

function promiseRoute(file){
  return fs.readFileAsync(file, "utf8")
  .then(JSON.parse)
  .then(function(file){
    if(!file.url) throw new Error("missing url")
    router.get(file.url, function(req, res, next){
      return res.redirect("/hello")
    })
    return router
  })
}

app.use(promiseRoute("../file.json"))

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {})
```

also tried

```
promiseRoute(path.join(__dirname, "./file.json")).then(app.use)
```

And I'm getting this error.

```
throw new TypeError('app.use() requires middleware functions')
```

And this with the promise.

```
Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'lazyrouter' of undefined
    at use (/project/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:213:7)
    at tryCatcher (/project/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/util.js:24:31)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/project/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:489:31)
    at Promise._settlePromiseAt (/project/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:565:18)
    at Promise._settlePromises (/project/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:681:14)
    at Async._drainQueue (/project/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:123:16)
    at Async._drainQueues (/project/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:133:10)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/project/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:15:14)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:371:17)
```

Also tried this:

```
promiseRoute(path.join(__dirname, "./file.json")).then(function(router){
  app.use(function(req, res, next){
    return router
  })
})
```

How can I return promise / route to `app.use`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

app.use requires middleware function. That is, a function that takes `(req, res, next)`.

So overall:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
     promiseRoute(probably_pass_things_in).nodeify(next);
});
```

The nodeify is to convert a promise to a callback `next` will take. Note there is third party promise middleware for express you can use.

Comment: Hey Benjamin! Thanks! I'm trying to have a route in a file and pass it to `app.use` like this http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#router and I'm having trouble wrapping my head around returning that `route` within that promise.

Comment: `app.use` takes either the `router` object or the anon `function(req, res, next)` I don't think I can return a `router` object within the `function(req, res, next)` it's hanging the server.

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick:

```
promiseRoute(path.join(__dirname, "./file.json")).then(function(router){
  app.use(router)
})
```