# Running asynchronous code when express server starts

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise, bluebird

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31225249/returning-a-promised-wrapped-express-route-to-app-use) I got something like this working.

```
promiseRoute().bind(app).then(app.use)
```

What I didn't realize at the time is that this correctly adds the returned `route` from the promise to `app.use` however if there is a subsequent `app.use` after this statement (for instance an error call) expresses router system will run the error routes before it runs the promise returned route.

I'd have to wrap all calls within a promise chain and return app from within a promise which causes more problems when I have to use it.

Is there any system / library / etc for managing this?

I fundamentally want to run a asynchronous function when the server starts and not every time on a specific route. So I need code running above `app.use` or code within `app.use` that checks if that async function has run or not. Thoughts?

This is the code I have that jumps right to `404` for my `/google` request.

```
var googleRoute = require("./google-route")

googleRoute.on("redirect", function(req, res, next){
  return res.redirect(req.googleRedirect)
})

googleRoute.on("tokens", function(req, res, next){
  return res.json(req.googleTokens)
})

// returns express route
googleRoute.use({
  "toRedirectUrl": "/google",
  "appCredentials": path.join(__dirname, "google-tokens.json"),
  "genetateAuth": {
    "approval_prompt": "force",
    "access_type": 'offline',
    "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
  }
}).bind(app).then(app.use)

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});
```

Comment: please post the code from the previous question here

Comment: added some code above

Comment: *"Is there any system / library / etc for managing this?"* You're already using it. Just add another .then with a callback.

Comment: @KevinB what are you talking about?

Comment: `googleRoute.use` returns a thenable, you can just chain another .then onto it and define the rest of your routes there. `.then(function () {app.use(somemiddleware);});`

Comment: What version of node.js/io.js are you using?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum iojs v2.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do here is always keep the `app` variable at the top level.

```
let app = express()

app.use(...)

export defaults app
```

If you want to run something before the app server starts, it should be wrapped around requests that starts the server.

```
checkIfDatabaseIsUp().then(() => {
  let server = http.createServer(app)
})
```